# Why does 'Pi' exist in my language bar?

Tags: 14.04, ibus

I have disabled ibus since it has memory leak. After I restarted my system, there is a 'Pi' symbol in my language bar.

[image]

I also removed ibus-pinyin, ibus-sunpinyin and restarted OS. So how can I remove this 'Pi'?

Comment: you never can remove π because it is a fundamental constant! :-))

Comment: Open "Text Entry Settings..." and remove the pinyin keyboard.